# jackcess - database pathname in databasebuilder.open

Tags: java, jackcess

I have a Microsoft Access database called perso.accdb. I use the Jackcess library to try to open it using the following code taken from official documentation here

Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("mydb.mdb"));
Sounds simple enough, but where exactly do I place my "perso.accdb"?! else how to write an absolute pathname?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file location is the string argument to the `File` object constructor. For a path relative to the current OS working directory in effect when your application runs you can use

```java
Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("datafiles/perso.accdb"));
```

For an absolute path you can use something like

```java
Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("C:/path/to/perso.accdb"));
```

Comment: I tried absolute path, but i get following error Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

Comment: The `DatabaseBuilder.open` method might throw an `IOException` so you need to handle it. Either `catch` it or add a `throws` clause to your own method definition.